# How to detect a Clickjacking attack in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, jakarta-ee, clickjacking

I have tried a click-jacking tool. It's able to detect only the hidden frames in the HTML page. I studied about the click-jacking attack, as illustrated by the references below, and I think frame busting attack is able to detect that tool if any duplicate frame is present in the HTML code.

But I need the tool to provide the details of whether the given web URL can possibly include a click-jacking attack.

### References:

[IETF Standard against Clickjacking](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gondrom-frame-options-02)

[Introduction on Click-jacking basics](http://www.slideshare.net/novogeek/clickjacking-devcon2011)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you disable the clickjacking attacks altogether by adding the The `X-Frame-Options` to the response header?

[here's how](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

Comment: Kamy, Thanks for your response. I have already added the X-Frame-Options in the response header to avoid the clickjacking attack. but here My question is, the tool to detect the clickjacking attack from the given URL(Web page). I have tool named web security scanner 0.9, it will detect the Cross-site request forgery attack from the given URL. Likewise i need to know the tool to identify the clickjacking attack from the given URL.

Comment: 2.Can we predict clickjacking attack by knowing the response header ?